# Alert is confusing me!

Tags: javascript, jquery, function-calls

```
function convertDateFormat(){
//  alert("hi");
     $(".tour-dates ul li").each(function(){
//      alert(monthConvert($(this).find(".month").text()));
        var replace = monthConvert($(this).find(".month").text());
        $(this).find(".month").text(replace);
    });
}
```

I have the above function in a js file and i'm calling it from `$(document).ready(function(){...`

you can see i have two alert statements that are commented.

if they are commented the function doesn't seem to be called because the changes aren't reflected.
If i remove the comment and let the alert work, the changes appear!

What am I doing wrong?

FYI:
The monthConvert function:

```
function monthConvert(monthInt){    

    var monthArray = new Array();

        monthArray["1"]="JAN";
        monthArray["2"]="FEB";
        monthArray["3"]="MAR";
        monthArray["4"]="APR";
        monthArray["5"]="MAY";
        monthArray["6"]="JUN";
        monthArray["7"]="JUL";
        monthArray["8"]="AUG";
        monthArray["9"]="SEP";
        monthArray["10"]="OCT";
        monthArray["11"]="NOV";
        monthArray["12"]="DEC";

    return monthArray[monthInt];
}
```

Comment: Minimal testcase please. It should include your monthConvert function - if an error occurs in there the function appears to do nothing but the alerts are shown before that function ins called so they'd work anyway.

Comment: Don't use alerts as they don't give you a true picture of what your function is really doing. Instead, use console.info() with Firebug or WebKit Developer Tools. This way you can see the logging statements and still see your code run without blocking behaviors.

Comment: doesn't console.info() create JS errors in IE browsers? btw are console.info() and console.log() the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could check your browsers JavaScript logs for errors.

In Internet Explorer 9 press <kbd>F12</kbd>

In Firefox download firebug.

In Chrome press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

Comment: Perhaps also, for the time being move this function into your inline script for testing purposes.

Comment: I have firebug and i checked the error console. There is no error :(

Comment: Have you tried moving the code to the inline script tags? Also, you could try adding some dynamic paramaters to your javascript script src. eg, `<script src='js/functions.js?time=<?php echo(time()); ?>' />`

Comment: what does this parameter do: ?time=

Comment: It does nothing on the serverside but if the URL changes every time the page loads the browser wont ever get a chance to cache it because if the URL changes it treats it like an entirely new URL.

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript file is cached by browser. Just disable the cache or Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh page.

Comment: That wouldn't cause the function to just stop working just because alerts were commented. The OP is saying that if the comments are removed, it just doesn't work at all. If it were caching issues, OP would still see the alerts, not nothing at all.

Comment: I have tried Ctrl + F5 , Ctrl + Shift + R , Ctrl + R ... No change :(

Comment: @Pack Hack can you post your html? Are you loading content through AJAX, or are you calling function before html is loaded?

Comment: My HTML<ul><li >
    
<div class="date">
<span class="dayow">Thu</span>
<span class="month">6</span>
<span class="day">9</span>
</div>

</li>

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly what's going on without seeing the complete HTML, but a minimal test case from your code above seems to work, with or without the alerts: http://jsfiddle.net/g_thom/5ChNh/

So, your problems seem to lie elsewhere than the code so far provided.